# MUI Badge is not showing in the DOM, in inspector the span is in tact

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, badge

I've created a React RTK application with mainly MUI Components.
Suddenly (and I can' reconstruct where when or why) the Mui `<Badge>` is not showing in my app, although it is in plain sight in the DevTools, elements.

[image]

The code that leads to this example page is:

```
import { Badge, Button } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";

export default () => (
  <div>
    <Badge variant="dot" badgevalue={10}>
      <Button variant="outlined">test</Button>
    </Badge>
  </div>
);
```

I've tried a lot, but with no succes. Can anyone help me out what the problem is here?

Answer (score 0):

you have not added `color` props to badge. thats why its not displaying. also I checked the badge API. there is no `badgeValue` props. but there is `badgeContent` props. https://mui.com/api/badge/

```
<div>
  <Badge variant="dot" badgevalue={10} color="primary">
    <Button variant="outlined">test</Button>
  </Badge>
  <Badge variant="dot" badgeContent={10} color="primary">
    <Button variant="outlined">test</Button>
  </Badge>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code and it worked on my machine.
make sure to:

- `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`
- `npm install @mui/icons-material @mui/material @emotion/styled @emotion/react`

The order doesn't matter just install both.